# Which algorithm does gdal_polygonize use?

Tags: gdal, algorithm, polygonize

I would like to know which algorithm (i.e. [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) ) is used to extract the polygons in gdal_polygonizer. I searched [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) and [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a3f522a9035d3512b5d414fb4752671b1) but could not find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

polygonize is not a segmentation algorithm, it is a region grouping algorithm (only group pixel that touch and have the exact same value), so there is no special operator. Basically here is what it does (probably optimized) :

```
initialise region count at zero

you run through all pixel

assign a value of region count to the first pixel that you  meet 

if the next pixel is connected (adjacent and same value, optionnally with 4 or 8 connectedness) to a previously labelled pixel, 

assign the value of this pixel to the new pixel.

else

increase the region count by one and assign the region count value to the new pixel.
```

then convert to polygon feature

Comment: How does the conversion to polygon feature look like?

Comment: polygon boundaries follow the sides of the pixels, so you have a "stair" look that can be smoothed with simplification or smoothing algorithms for vector data.